# Ctrl+Click to open in new tab

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android

I use ASUS Transformer with the keyboard attached.

In Google Chrome for Android, I would like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click to open up a new tab which contains the website where the link is pointing to, just as I would on my desktop computer. But somehow this does not work on my Android device? I can use for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to open new window.

BTW I click with my touchscreen, maybe this matters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, AFAIK, every action associated with a mouse click can be accessed using a touch or a long-touch. Combo using a key-press and a touch aren't well supported *(if supported at all)*.

Long-Touch over a link, gives you a popup with:

- Open in new Tap;
- Open in incognito mode;
- Copy link address;
- Save link as.

For future reference, Google Chrome shortcuts link, from Google support page (the majority of the Linux links are available for Android... just waiting to have this page updated with the Android shortcuts list):

Google Chrome - [Keyboard and mouse shortcuts](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171571)